# What does it mean to say that A is an $\Bbb F_3$ endomorphism?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

What does it mean to say that A is an $\Bbb F_3$ endomorphism of F .

Where $F:=\Bbb F_3(\beta)$, and we define $A:F\rightarrow F$ where $A(x)=\beta x $ $\forall x\in F$ ?

I know that an endomorphism is a homomorphism from an object to itself. the part that confuses me is that its an $\Bbb F_3$ endomorphism. It would make more sense to me if it was an $\Bbb F_{27}$ endomorphism as F is isomorphic to this field.

I'm supposing that the fact that $x$ is mapped onto $ \beta x$ is what makes it an $\Bbb F_3$ endomorphism but I dont really understand how as I would have thought that it still maps 27 elements onto 27 elements ?

Comment: It probably means $A$ viewed as an endomorphism of linear spaces over $\Bbb{F}_3$. It can't mean an endomorphism of rings as $\beta1 \neq 1$. What is the context?

Comment: @RobArthan it's in relation to linear spaces

Comment: In that case, it almost certainly means endomorphism of linear spaces over $\Bbb{F}_3$. It's really a question for your teacher rather than MSE.

Comment: @RobArthan perhaps you could vote to close it then, i'd delete it but repeated deletion of answered questions can result in removal from the site :/

Comment: That's entirely up to you. Why not leave the question here and let us know what your teacher said.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Good Idea, I will :)

Comment: Have you covered polymorphisms in class? If so, there is a quick way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{F}_3$ endomorphism means it's an endomorphism which additionally fixes $\mathbb{F}_3$, and is $\mathbb{F}_3$ linear.
In particular, for any $k \in \mathbb{F}_3$, $f(k x) = k f(x)$ and $f(k) = k$.

Comment: Metha I don't understand how f(k)=k, where k$\in \Bbb F_3$ here , wouldn't we get say $f(2)=2 \beta$ where 2 is an element of $\Bbb F_3$ ?

Comment: The given example doesn't fix $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Comment: and it also is $\Bbb F_{27}$-linear